# I can not to get url of my image in Angular Version 11

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-storage, angularfire

I am using FireStorage in my Angular project in the **Angular CLI version: 11.2.6** but when I get the url of the image uploaded with the command **this.dowloadUrl.getDownloadURL()**

I have an input text in which I show it but I can't get that data to be able to operate it.

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import { UploadScriptsService } from 'src/app/services/upload-scripts.service';
import { finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';
/*importo el servicio conectionService para mandar datos*/
import { ConectionService } from 'src/app/services/conection.service';
/*importo el Storage de firebase */
import { AngularFireStorage } from '@angular/fire/storage';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-card',
  templateUrl: './add-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-card.component.css']
})
export class AddCardComponent implements OnInit {


  private script: UploadScriptsService = new UploadScriptsService;
  @ViewChild('imageUser') inputImageUser: ElementRef | undefined;

  /*Variables con las cuales envio los datos para cargar a firebase*/
  item: any = {
    title: '',
    text: '',
    image: ''
  };

  imageSrc: string = "";
  userFile: any;
  imageSelected: any;

/*  DECLARO LAS VARIABLES PARA PODER ENVIAR LA IMAGEN Y OBTENER SU URL */
  imgUrl: Observable<string | any>; 
  uploadPercent: Observable<number | any>; 
  

  constructor(private conection: ConectionService, private storage: AngularFireStorage) {
    this.uploadPercent = new Observable;
    this.imgUrl = new Observable;
  }

  


  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.script.cargaScripts(["uploadCard"])
  }


  addCard() {
    this.conection.addCard(this.item);
    this.item.title = '';
    this.item.text = '';
    this.item.image = '';

  }

  onUpload(e: any)  {
    /* console.log("subir", e.target.files[0]); */

    const id = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2);
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    const filePath = `imagesCards/${id}`;
    const fileRef = this.storage.ref(filePath);
    //Subo la foto
    const task = this.storage.upload(filePath, file);
    //observo el porcentaje de la carga de la imagen
    this.uploadPercent = task.percentageChanges();

    //obtengo el url de la foto
    task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      finalize(() => { 
        this.imgUrl = fileRef.getDownloadURL()
      })
      )
      .subscribe()
      
      console.log('My ImageUrl' + this.imgUrl);

  }



}
```

In my HTML I use an **<input type = "text2>** where I show the URL of the image I uploaded, but I don't know how I do to get that data and put it in an **<img src" ">**. I attach the part of the HTML code with a short display image

```html
 <input #imageUser
  type="text"
  style="margin-top:auto;"
  [value]="urlImage | async">
```

[image: visualization of my front end]

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
 <img #imageUser
  [src]="urlImage | async">
```

Comment: I would like to use the **<input #imageUser
  type="text"
  style="margin-top:auto;"
  [value]="urlImage | async">**  data to put it here  **<input  type="text" name= "image" name="title" [(ngModel)]="item.image">**

Comment: I tried what you told me and look what I get when inspecting the code

**<img _ngcontent-jpx-c52="" id="imageSecond" src="">**

Comment: if what you told me works, but I want to send that url to my firebase database, something like this

**<textarea class="form-control" type="text"  name="text" [(ngModel)]="item.text"></textarea>**